# spooky error Child terminated with non-zero exit code 127

Tags: casperjs

I saw another question on here that seemed to be a very similar issue, but the "answer" was something along the lines of "Ok, I fixed it" from the creator of SpookyJS.  But I'm still getting the error.

Basically, I'm trying to run SpookyJS and using the latest version from an npm install.  I have both CasperJS and PhantomJS installed and in the PATH (In fact, if I just run a CasperJS script, it works).  My world.js is copied directly from the github page but when I run a very simple script, it throws an error while parsing the world.js file and simply says:

```
spooky error{[Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 127] details: {code:127, signal: null}}
```

Help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just found that it seems like it makes it out of the world.js file after all but never makes it into the next snippet of code that begins with "this.Given('My Given String', function(callback){...."

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but may be this answer can help someone looking for this error, as I was some hours ago.

In my case, I got this error because I haven't installed phantomjs. If you use npm, you can do it using npm install -g phantomjs.

Kind regards,